# defining different direction PHP

Tags: html, css

The phone number, email and date fields should be left to right and name, and family fields should be right to left.

```
<?php
echo '<input type="hidden" name="name" value="' . $amch["name"] . '">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="family" value="' . $amch["family"] . '">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="phone_number" value="' . $amch["phone_number"] . '">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="email" value="' . $amch["email"] . '">';
$date= 1394-08-24
echo"$name", " " , "$family", " " , "$phone_number", "$email", "$date";
?>
```

Comment: You mean right aligned (`text-align: right`), or actual right to left reading (`direction:RTL`)? Both can be done using CSS. This is mainly an HTML or CSS property and is basically unrelated to PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use css?
change your code to:

```
<style>
    .rtl { direction: rtl; text-align: right; }
    .ltr { direction: ltr; text-align: left; }
</style>
<?php
echo '<input type="hidden" class="rtl" name="name" value="' . $amch["name"] . '">';
echo '<input type="hidden" class="rtl" name="family" value="' . $amch["family"] . '">';
echo '<input type="hidden" class="ltr" name="phone_number" value="' . $amch["phone_number"] . '">';
echo '<input type="hidden" class="ltr" name="email" value="' . $amch["email"] . '">';
$date= 1394-08-24
echo"$name", " " , "$family", " " , "$phone_number", "$email", "$date";
?>
```